# Combine multiple lists into a specific string format using Python

Tags: python

I have a very specific problem.
I have six lists that I need to combine into one big string.
Every list will be enclosed inside a bracket () in final big string.

For example, I have declared six lists as below:

```
primaryP=['PSUP']
primaryG=['NSUP']
primaryAin=['IBIAS_200N','VREF']
primaryAout=['IOUTN','IOUTP','IBIAS_OUT<1:0>','ICAL<1:0>']
primaryDin=['DN', 'DNB', 'EN', 'FAST_START', 'RESET', 'UP', 'UPB', 'DEGEN_TRIM<2:0>']
primaryDout=[]
```

Now I want to combine all six lists into one big string as shown below:

```
CSRPGPrimary='//CSRPG PRIMARY ("PSUP") ("NSUP") ("IBIAS_200N" "VREF") ("IOUTN" "IOUTP" "IBIAS_OUT<1>" "IBIAS_OUT<0>" "ICAL<1>" "ICAL<0>") ("DN" "DNB" "EN" "FAST_START" "RESET" "UP" "UPB" "DEGEN_TRIM<2>" "DEGEN_TRIM<1>" "DEGEN_TRIM<0>") ()'
```

Notice how I want every list inside individual brackets () and each element in double quotes "". Also I want to split bus/vector bits individually in final string as shown above.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
primaryP=['PSUP']
primaryG=['NSUP']
primaryAin=['IBIAS_200N','VREF']
primaryAout=['IOUTN','IOUTP','IBIAS_OUT<1:0>','ICAL<1:0>']
primaryDin=['DN', 'DNB', 'EN', 'FAST_START', 'RESET', 'UP', 'UPB', 'DEGEN_TRIM<3:0>']
primaryDout=[]

primaryMaster=[primaryP, primaryG, primaryAin, primaryAout, primaryDin, primaryDout]
CSRPGPrimary=['("'+' '.join(item)+'")' if item else '()' for item in primaryMaster]
CSRPGPrimary="//CSRPG PRIMARY " + ' '.join(CSRPGPrimary)

print("CSRPGPrimary=", CSRPGPrimary)
```

But final output is not as I wanted:

```
Final output:
('CSRPGPrimary=', '//CSRPG PRIMARY ("PSUP") ("NSUP") ("IBIAS_200N VREF") ("IOUTN IOUTP IBIAS_OUT<1:0> ICAL<1:0>") ("DN DNB EN FAST_START RESET UP UPB DEGEN_TRIM<1:0> GAIN_SEL<1:0> GAIN_TRIM<3:0> OFFSET_MODE<1:0> OFFSET_TRIM<3:0> RES_TRIM<4:0> SEL_IRN<1:0> SEL_IRP<1:0>") ()')

Desired output:
('CSRPGPrimary=', '//CSRPG PRIMARY ("PSUP") ("NSUP") ("IBIAS_200N" "VREF") ("IOUTN" "IOUTP" "IBIAS_OUT<1>" "IBIAS_OUT<0>" "ICAL<1>" "ICAL<0>") ("DN" "DNB" "EN" "FAST_START" "RESET" "UP" "UPB" "DEGEN_TRIM<2>" "DEGEN_TRIM<1>" "DEGEN_TRIM<0>") ()')
```

any suggestions, especially what is best way to split vector/bus bits?

Comment: It looks like you want to do the `"`-wrapping to each of the elements you join, but your code is doing it to the result of the join. It's just a matter of swapping that order.

Comment: Wait, do you actually want `"IBIAS"_"200N"` instead of `"IBIAS_200N"`? If so, what's the rule for that? Split on non-alpha characters, quote the bits, and rejoin? Or…?

Comment: it was a typo, corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simpler to do this in steps. If you really want to merge it all back into one monster listcomp that you can't debug, you can do that after you get it working.

The first thing we want to do is turn each bus-bits spec into separate elements. This is the trickiest bit. I'm not sure of the exact rule you're using, but it would go something like this:

```
def split_bus_bits(lst):
    for element in lst:
        if element.endswith('>'):
            base, _, bits = element[:-1].partition('<')
            hi, lo = bits.split(':')
            for i in range(int(lo), int(hi)+1):
                yield f'{base}<{i}>'
        else:
            yield element
```

Or, if you can understand regular expressions, this seems like a good job for one:

```
rbusbits = re.compile(r'(\w+)(?:<(\d+):(\d+)>)?')
def split_bus_bits(lst):
    for element in lst:
        base, hi, lo = rbusbits.match(element).groups()
        if hi:
            for i in range(int(lo), int(hi)+1):
                yield f'{base}<{i}>'
        else:
            yield base
```

And now, we can expand out each sublist:

```
busbitsified = (split_bus_bits(sublist) for sublist in primaryMaster)
```

The remaining steps are all a lot simpler. For each list, we want to put each element in quotes:

```
quoted = ([f'"{element}"' for element in sublist] for sublist in busbitsified)
```

Next, join each sublist:

```
joined = (' '.join(sublist) for sublist in quoted)
```

Next, put parens around each string-that-was-a-joined-up-sublist:

```
parenthesized = (f'({sublist})' for sublist in joined)
```

And finally, join them into one big string:

```
CSRPGPrimary="//CSRPG PRIMARY " + ' '.join(parenthesized)
```

And the result seems to be your desired one:

```
'//CSRPG PRIMARY ("PSUP") ("NSUP") ("IBIAS_200N" "VREF") ("IOUTN" "IOUTP" "IBIAS_OUT<1:0>" "ICAL<1:0>") ("DN" "DNB" "EN" "FAST_START" "RESET" "UP" "UPB" "DEGEN_TRIM<3:0>") ()'
```

Notice that I didn't have to do anything special for `()`. An empty sublist will quote no elements, join those no elements into an empty string, and then parenthesize that empty string.

---

If you're not using Python 3.6+, or just don't understand f-strings, you can replace those with your favorite calls to `str.format` or `%` or just concatenation (e.g., `'"' + element + '"'`).

---

From your output, it looks like you're using Python 2.7, but writing code as if you were using Python 3. In which case you should probably either `from __future__ import print_function`, or change your `print` statements to remove the extraneous parentheses. Unless you actually *wanted* to print a tuple of the reprs of two strings, instead of just printing two strings. In that case, carry on.

Comment: any suggestions on splitting bus bits?

Comment: Yes I'm using python 2.7. adding below line give me an error. from __future__ import print_function     Here is the error msg:    print "No module found!!"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @sanforyou Are you sure you typed that right, with two underscores around `future`? (Or just copy and paste it from the answer.)

Comment: @sanforyou For the "splitting bus bits", I'll update the answer.

Comment: @sanforyou OK, I've got something that works and that hopefully you can understand. (Let me know if you can't.) Although really, this spec is bordering on complicated enough that you might want to parse it, transform it with a tree-visitor, and then build the output from the tree.

Comment: Yes, I tried  with two underscores around future, like they way you typed but weird I get an error. Moreover, I tried both functions for split_bus_bits but I get errors in both at yield statements. any idea why?      yield f'{base}<{i}>'
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @sanforyou Read the whole answer; there's a paragraph about what to do instead of f-strings if you're not using Python 3.6 or later (which you're not).

Comment: Anyway, where does that `print "No module found!!"` come from? Are you by any chance trying to do the `from __future__ import print_function` locally in a function or something? You can't do that; `future` statements have to come way up at the top of the file, before everything except for shbang line, encoding declarations, and docstrings.

Comment: I tried with python 3.6 and it works great. regex function for bus bit expansion is working as expected however the first function outputs full bus width as well. I like the regex one though. CSRPGPrimary= //CSRPG PRIMARY ("PSUP") ("NSUP") ("IBIAS_200N" "VREF") ("IOUTN" "IOUTP" "IBIAS_OUT<1:0><0>" "IBIAS_OUT<1:0><1>" "ICAL<1:0><0>" "ICAL<1:0><1>") ("DN" "DNB" "EN" "FAST_START" "RESET" "UP" "UPB" "DEGEN_TRIM<3:0><0>" "DEGEN_TRIM<3:0><1>" "DEGEN_TRIM<3:0><2>" "DEGEN_TRIM<3:0><3>") ()

Comment: Here is screenshot how I am using future import for print : https://imgur.com/a/guB6c

Comment: @sanforyou Oh, I see. Yeah, if you use that future statement to _allow_ you to do Python 3-style print functions, then you have to _only_ use Python 3-style print functions; your Python 2-style print statements will break. You have to pick one or the other consistently.

Comment: @sanforyou Oh, the first version, I went through all that trouble to split out `base`, and then used `element` instead. Easy fix…

Comment: Thank you very much. All issues resolved. Pepped and accepted as solution.

Comment: Can I add space inside parenthesis when sublist is empty, i.e. instead () I want it like ( ) but only if it is empty. Can I do this with one liner by modifying below code?  parenthesized = (f'({sublist})' for sublist in joined)

Comment: @abernert I did it with a for loop and then if statement but one line would be nice.

Comment: @sanforyou You probably want a step either right before or right after parenthesization. The first would be something like `spaced = (sublist if sublist else ' ' for sublist in joined)`, the second something like `spaced = ('( )' if substr == '()' else substr for substr in parenthesized)`. If you understand how either of those works, you can merge it into the previous or next step in the pipeline pretty easily.

Comment: @sanforyou Also, it's worth learning how to translate comprehensions into for statements and back. `[f(x) for x in xs if p(x)]` is the same as `result=[]` then `for x in xs:` then `if p(x):` then `result.append(f(x))`. The clauses of the comprehension just become nested statements, in order. The only difference with a generator expression (using parens instead of square brackets) is that it doesn't have to build a list in memory, it gives you the values lazily on demand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I get it now. and I tried both and it worked. I implemented this one just because its easier to read: spaced = ('( )' if substr == '()' else substr for substr in parenthesized)

Comment: @sanforyou There's a great presentation called [Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) that explains more about this style of organizing your code into a sequence of generator expressions. I think David Beazley explains it better than I ever could, even if I weren't limited by the scope of a StackOverflow answer and comments, so you should check it out.

Comment: I want to remove all integer/floats(1.1.8. 2 etc) with empty brackets. what is the best to way to do it? I tried below line after busbitsfied: removeDigits=(['()' if element.isdigit() else element for element in sublist] for sublist in busbitsified)

Comment: Looks like isdigit only looks for an interger number, parsing float seems tricky with one liner

Comment: Ok I ended up writing a function "is_number" to detect int/float.. now I get the right output but I still have quotes around it?  removeDigits=(['' if is_number(element) else element for element in sublist] for sublist in busbitsified)       and here is the output: CSRPGPrimary= //CSRPG PRIMARY  ("") ("NSUP") ( ) .........